# Which partition contains my C drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I'm trying to install Windows 8 on my laptop (currently running Windows 7). I am presented with a dialog where two drives are shown, along with their sizes.

I don't know which of the partitions contains the C drive. How can I find it out without having to restart my computer?

Comment: There is no C **drive**. Drives typical contain partitions. Partitions (or less common whole drives when dangerously dedicated) may contain volumes.  Windows may label once such volume C:.  Simply look up volume is mapped as c: as assume it is C:

Comment: @Hennes  Simply look up volume is mapped as c, I could not get it. I don't want to restart.

Comment: Your going to have to restart.  You should select the partition that contains Window 7 on it, of course, if you started the upgrade process within Windows this is done for you.

Comment: I hope you have an image of your Windows 7 before you start destoying it. Because what are you going to do if yout W8 installation does not work ?

Comment: You should select the partition that contains Window 7 on it. Is there no way to know which partition contains C, without restarting?

Comment: @whs Yes I have.

Comment: Typically the C partition that contains the OS is the biggest partition. Ususally there are 2 more partitions - the 100MB system partition and a recovery partition that is appr. 10GB.

Comment: @whs I don't think. I want to know any method where I can be certain that this partition contains C drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use **DiskPart** to help you out.

1. You need to run *command prompt*. On the screen where Windows Installer shows *Install now* button, click *Repair your computer* link (bottom-left part of the windows). Then there should be a *Open command prompt* option – go for it.
2. Run diskpart (type `diskpart` and hit ENTER). Now, your command prompt should start with `DISKPART>`.
3. To display all disks available, type following command (and hit ENTER): `LIST DISK`
4. In your case, there should be `Disk 0` and `Disk 1`. Pick one – e.g. *Disk 0* – by typing `SELECT DISK 0`
5. Type `LIST VOLUME`

You will be provided with a list of volumes ("drives") present on the disk. There will be column called *Ltr* in the table. That column displays letter assigned to the specific volume – here you should be looking for the C letter.

If you will not find the *volume* on *Disk 0*, type `SELECT DISK 1` and again `LIST VOLUME` – it will definitely be on the second disk then.

Disk number from `SELECT DISK` command should be the same as the disk number in the installation dialog (*Disk X: Partition Y*). Also `LIST DISK` command shows the size of each disk, so you can double check.

Comment: I am checking all your instructions in windows 10 command prompt 
but in Both disk 0 and Disk 1 all volumes are  dicto same.

Comment: In the spirit of the original question: If you don't see any letters in the Ltr column, then none of the volumes has the letter assigned. Either you have more disks in your system or none of the "partitions" (volumes) has the letter you seek assigned.